# Adding PCL package into my project

Tags: xamarin, plugins, xamarin.forms, media, video-recording

I am having a problem using the package

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

The way my project structure is: I have two Project in a solution.
Former one is name as "Common","Common.Droid" and "Common.iOS" and later one is "Demo", "Demo.Droid" and "Demo.iOS".

The Common project are to implement commonly used code which i can reuse on other projects, whereas the Demo project are the actual program to be run on the device.

I have installed and setup the package under "Common" project, I am sure I have added the related package to Droid and iOS from nuget to the "Common" project.

When it start to call:

```
CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
```

I received an error:

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

Droid package.config

```
> > <packages>   <package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Plugin.CurrentActivity" version="1.0.1"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package id="Plugin.Permissions"
> version="1.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
> />   <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable"
> version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package
> id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0"
> targetFramework="monoandroid70" />   <package id="Xamarin.Forms"
> version="2.3.3.175" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

Packages.config for PCL part:

```
> <packages>
  <package id="PCLStorage" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Rox.Xamarin.Camera" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Media" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.3.175" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

After looking at the source code of their API, I found this:

```
  static IMedia CreateMedia()
        {
#if PORTABLE
            return null;
#else
            return new MediaImplementation();
#endif
        }
```

I think it hit the return null part.... But how... I have added the portable, android, iOS version in.

Comment: You added it to the Native project(s) too, right? Same Version? Maybe it screwed the platform moniker. Can you please post the lines from your packages.config and the contents of the nicer package in your packages folder (inside of the solution folder)?

Comment: I have added the packages.config for droid part. I tried their sample and works fine. I think when I started to call CrossMedia.Current, it started to fail

Comment: It may be hitting the return null part which saying #if PORTABLE... but aren't this project supposed to be used for PCL ...

Comment: Could you try changing the monodroid70 behind the media packages *targetframework* to just monodroid or monodroid60. In the Nuget Packages .zip, there should be a folder with the same name.

Comment: No it still doesn't work. Do I need to add the package on Demo Project as well even though Project of the Demo using the Common project to call MediaPlugin. e.g. Common.Droid.Common.Initi() where inside the code I have called CrossPlugin.Current.

Comment: @LittleFunny Did you find a way to solve this issue! I am getting the same exception in the Permission plugin in android